# Internal LAN Based Chat/Messenger with LDAP/Active Directory Auth

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, instant-messaging, chat

Are there any options out there for an internal chat messenger that offers logging in with an AD account?

I've found some options out there for internal chat messengers but none seem to support AD.

Answer (score -1):

The most obvious option is [Microsoft Lync](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/).